# React update component on change props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Hi I am using React hooks and i build LogIn component like here:

```
    const [inputs, updateInputs] = useState(
    [
        {
            type: 'email',
            label: 'Email',
            name: 'email',
            value: '',
            error: false
        },
        {
            type: 'password',
            label: 'Password',
            name: 'password',
            value: '',
            error: false
        }
    ]
    );

    const renderInputs = () => {
        const inputsArr: typeof Input = [];

        inputs.map((item, i) => {
            inputsArr.push(
            <Input key={i} type={item.type} label={item.label} name={item.name} error={item.error}
                   onChange={inputOnChange}/>
            );
        });

        return inputsArr;
    };

    const onButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
        const data = {
            email: inputs[0].value,
            password: inputs[1].value
        }

        let newInputs = inputs;

        if(!data.email.length) {
            newInputs[0].error = true;
            updateInputs(newInputs);
            return false;
        }

        dispatch(signIn(data));
        return true;
    }, []);
```

I need to catch errors on click. But on click Component Input is not updated. I tried add `renderInputs` into `useEffect` and renderInputs like state but there i got infinity loop.

Can someone help me what's the right way please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all renderInputs is redundant, since the map returns an array:

```
const renderInputs = () => inputs.map((item, i) => <Input
       key={i} // index should also not be used as key
       type={item.type}
       label={item.label}
       name={item.name}
       error={item.error}
       onChange={inputOnChange}/>
);
```

Your onButtonClick is using useCallback with `[]` as second parameter. It will always return the same because it never gets updated. Either put `inputs` in the brackets or remove the useCallback since it will not improve your performance anyway (it will actually be slower).

You also do not update your inputs because you are mutating your inputs instead of updating them immutable ( `let newInputs = inputs;` is the same as before, so you are just mutating inputs and saves the same object again, and useState will not update if the shallow reference is the same as before).

Try this:

```
let newInputs = [...inputs];

if(!data.email.length) {
     newInputs[0].error = true;
     updateInputs(newInputs);
     return false;
 }

 dispatch(signIn(data));
```